# Hamburger menu css hover not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I just need to show black color as the background color in my hamburger menu. But there is a problem. This hamburger menu using CSS :after and :before classes. If I hover over them, it will hover one by one which is not I want. I want all 3 lines in the menu to be hover in black. like this.

[image]

I tried this way but it will show one by one.

```
.BurgerMenu:hover:after,
.BurgerMenu:hover,
.BurgerMenu:hover:before{
    background: #000;
}
```

```css
.BurgerMenu {
    position: relative;
    left: 6px;
    top: 26px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #979797;
}

.BurgerMenu:before {
    transition: all 0.25s;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -0.5em;
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #979797;
}
.BurgerMenu:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    top: 0.5em;
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #979797;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}

.BurgerMenu:hover:after,
.BurgerMenu:hover,
.BurgerMenu:hover:before{
 background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-storage" class="Navigation">
  <section class="Navigation--collapsed">
    <div class="BurgerMenu"></div>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m72w6trh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

background and border can do this easily without pseudo element:

```css
.BurgerMenu {
  position: relative;
  left: 6px;
  top: 26px;
  height: calc(6px + 1em);
  color: #979797;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25px;
  background: currentcolor content-box;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.BurgerMenu:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-storage" class="Navigation">
  <section class="Navigation--collapsed">
    <div class="BurgerMenu"></div>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Considering your code you can adjust it like below:

```css
.BurgerMenu {
    position: relative;
    left: 6px;
    top: 26px;
    height: calc(1em + 2px);
    padding:0.5em 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 25px;
    background: #979797 content-box;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}

.BurgerMenu:before {
    transition: all 0.25s;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #979797;
}
.BurgerMenu:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #979797;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}

.BurgerMenu:hover:after,
.BurgerMenu:hover,
.BurgerMenu:hover:before{
 background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-storage" class="Navigation">
  <section class="Navigation--collapsed">
    <div class="BurgerMenu"></div>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

The most optimal way to achieve this would be using separate `<div>`s instead of trying to create the icon using :after and :before. Then you end up with a much more readable CSS.

```css
.BurgerMenu {
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.BurgerMenuRow {
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #979797;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}

.BurgerMenu:hover .BurgerMenuRow {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-storage" class="Navigation">
    <section class="Navigation--collapsed">
        <div class="BurgerMenu">
            <div class="BurgerMenuRow"></div>
            <div class="BurgerMenuRow"></div>
            <div class="BurgerMenuRow"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: I can't  change :after :before because it's having lot of animations.

Comment: @Janath What kind of animations? The only animation in your original post is the transition.

Comment: This is just a simple example. I have a very complex one by my own.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will be able to use separate <div>s for that, just use selectors like `:nth-child()` instead of `:before` and `:after`.

Answer (score 0):

- We need to use 3 elements with the same `BurgerMenu` class with
  `margin: 5px;` style added instead of using `:before` and `:after`.
- Also give the hover effect on parent hover rather than hovering on
  the `BurgerMenu` element.

```css
.BurgerMenu {
    height: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #979797;
}


#nav-storage:hover .BurgerMenu{
 background: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-storage" class="Navigation">
  <section class="Navigation--collapsed">
    <div class="BurgerMenu"></div>
    <div class="BurgerMenu"></div>
    <div class="BurgerMenu"></div>
  </section>
</nav>
```